# Multiple exclusive union type

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```
interface IPositionChange {
    previousIndex: number;
    newIndex: number;
}

interface IVisibilityChange {
    index: number;
    panel: string;
}

interface IAction {
    action: 'paint' | 'clean';
}

interface IActionChange extends IAction, IVisibilityChange { }

// type IChange = (IVisibilityChange | IActionChange) & Partial<Record<keyof IPositionChange, never>>
//     | IPositionChange & Partial<Record<keyof IActionChange, never>> & Partial<Record<keyof IVisibilityChange, never>>;

// type IChange = IVisibilityChange & Partial<Record<keyof IPositionChange, never>> & Record<keyof IAction, never>
//     | IPositionChange & Partial<Record<keyof IActionChange, never>> & Partial<Record<keyof IVisibilityChange, never>>
//     | IActionChange & Partial<Record<keyof IPositionChange, never>>;

// type IChange = IVisibilityChange | IActionChange | IPositionChange;

function isPositionChange(change: IChange): change is IPositionChange {
    return !!change.previousIndex;
}

function isVisibilityChange(change: IChange): change is IVisibilityChange {
    return !!change.panel && !change.action;
}

function isActionChange(change: IChange): change is IActionChange {
    return !!change.panel && !!change.action;
}

function thisShouldNotCompile(change: IChange) {
    change = {
        previousIndex: 1,
        newIndex: 2,
        // either the ones above or the one below should throw and error,
        // as they should be exclusive.
        index: 0,
        panel: 'asd',
        action: 'paint',
    }
}
```

I am trying to make IActionChange not accept properties from multiple types, but only from a single one, i've commented some of my previous attempts and none seems to be working properly, as there is always some condition that is failed.

Im probably missing something pretty simple but can't quite put my finger on it, what is wrong with all these approaches ?

EDIT:

Changing the interfaces to this would cover all the case scenarios, and would make them exclusive, but i would rather not repeat unnecessary properties, as this would get more and more verbose as new properties are added:

```
interface IPositionChange {
  previousIndex: number;
  newIndex: number;
  action: never;
  index: never;
  panel: never;
}

interface IVisibilityChange {
  index: number;
  panel: string;
  previousIndex: never;
  newIndex: never;
  action: never;
}

interface IAction {
  action: 'paint' | 'clean';
  index: never;
  panel: never;
  previousIndex: never;
  newIndex: never;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an issue in the Typescript repository [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094) regarding this.

One of the answers proposed there is

```
type Without<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: undefined };
type XOR<T, U> = (Without<T> & U) | (Without<U> & T);
```

Now your code can be rewritten as

```
type Without<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: undefined };
type XOR<T, U> = (Without<T> & U) | (Without<U> & T);
type IChange = XOR<IPositionChange, IActionChange> | XOR<IVisibilityChange, IActionChange> | XOR<IPositionChange, IVisibilityChange>;
```

Explanation:

The `Without` type is expecting all the properties of `T` to be absent.

The `XOR` type is expecting all the properties of `T` to be present, and all the properties of `U` to be absent, or vice versa.

From there, you can use this to create a 3-way XOR.

Comment: That looks cleaner than what i have, and could be reused, but would hit the same wall "Property 'action' does not exist on type 'never'", please note that one of the types inherits another, and i think that is what is causing the biggest issue, and i cannot wrap my head around the why?

Comment: @MarioFigueiredo I have tested it, this works fine for all three of the types. Have you tested it yet?

Comment: yes, it was throwing the error i mentioned, here: https://shorturl.at/BCDFS

Comment: @MarioFigueiredo instead of `!!change.panel`, use `“panel” in change`. Similarly, use `!(“action” in change)` instead of `!change.action`. This way is more compatible and typesafe

Comment: yeah, like that seems to do it. here's your answer with a couple more test cases: shorturl.at/fhV36

Answer (score 1):

Would something likes this work for you ?
It uses the `in` operator to narrow the types in your functions.

```
interface IPositionChange {
  previousIndex: number;
  newIndex: number;
}

interface IVisibilityChange {
  index: number;
  panel: string;
}

interface IAction {
  action: 'paint' | 'clean';
}

interface IActionChange extends IAction, IVisibilityChange { }

type IChange = IVisibilityChange | IActionChange | IPositionChange;

function isPositionChange(change: IChange): change is IPositionChange {
  return 'previousIndex' in change;
}

function isVisibilityChange(change: IChange): change is IVisibilityChange {
  return 'panel' in change && 'action' in change && !change.action;
}

function isActionChange(change: IChange): change is IActionChange {
  return 'panel' in change && 'action' in change;
}
```

Comment: thats close, the issue there is that it allows to add properties it should not, have a look at the last scenario added: https://shorturl.at/cDHJ0 EDIT: also added the same case i mentioned on a question edit